# (C++) Factorizing this simple input/output code:

Tags: c++, optimization

### Anyone that could help me out, much appreciated!

I'd like this code to be as minimized as possible - however, I'd like it to display the exact same stuff.

Specifically, on how to remove some of the repetitions made within the code (such as "if, else if") etc. using other statements or making the compiler go through it faster, as I feel like I lack the experience and the knowledge to do this without messing up everything (such as using switch & case).

For example, when I test for "tf", I'd like not to be forced to repeat the "average" depending on whether or not we add the "TEZA" grade.

Thanks a lot, of course, I am willing to share more details if there's a need or if I'm not clear enough.

*I apologize in advance in case I'm not clear enough.*

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    string sub, tf;
    int m1, m2, m3, m4, sum, TEZA;
    double avg, tzm;

    cout << "SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR";
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "Subject at hand?: ";
    cin >> sub;
    cout << "\n" << "Input the FOUR marks you'd like verified: " << "\n";
    cout << "\n" << "M1: ";
    cin >> m1;
    cout << "\n" << "M2: ";
    cin >> m2;
    cout << "\n" << "M3: ";
    cin >> m3;
    cout << "\n" << "M4: ";
    cin >> m4;
    cout << "\n" << "Would you like to include the TEZA grade?(Y/N): ";
    cin >> tf;

    sum = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4;
    avg = (double) sum / 4;

    if (tf == "Y" | tf == "y")
    {
        cout << "What is the TEZA grade?: ";
        cin >> TEZA;
        int tzm = ((double) avg * 3 + TEZA) / 4;
        cout << "\n" << "Your average grade at " << sub << " is " << tzm << "\n"
             << "\n";

        cout << "You got the following mark: ";
        if (tzm >= 9 && tzm <= 10)
            cout << "A" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 8 && tzm <= 9)
            cout << "B" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 7 && tzm <= 8)
            cout << "C" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 6 && tzm <= 7)
            cout << "D" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 5 && tzm <= 6)
            cout << "E" << "\n";
        else if (tzm < 5)
            cout << "F" << "\n";

        if (tzm >= 5)
        {
            cout << "DO YOU PASS: " << "\n";
            cout << "Yes." << "\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "No." << "\n";
    }

    else

    {
        cout << "\n" << "Average at " << sub << " is " << avg << "\n" << "\n";

        cout << "You got the following mark: ";
        if (avg >= 9 && avg <= 10)
            cout << "A" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 8 && avg <= 9)
            cout << "B" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 7 && avg <= 8)
            cout << "C" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 6 && avg <= 7)
            cout << "D" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 5 && avg <= 6)
            cout << "E" << "\n";
        else if (avg < 5)
            cout << "F" << "\n";

        cout << "\n" << "DO YOU PASS?: " << "\n";

        if (avg >= 5)
            cout << "Yes." << "\n";
        else
            cout << "No." << "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: If the code works, and you just want to optimize it, then this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, you should ask on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau That code review site is pointing to some where else. It should be pointing to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware. I will post it there as well, pardon!

Comment: You can shorten the parts of the M using an array and a loop

Comment: @Asesh my link points to the right place. Look again

Comment: Optimization these days is complicated. It usually depends more on data-layout than instruction-count. (Cache misses take an eternity in computer years.) This particular code is un-optimizable because it is extremely IO bound, and the "I" in IO is a human.

Comment: I hope the @#$%^&* this isn't a homework assignment. If so, it may be the worst yet, and that's a lot of worst.

Comment: [Cross-posted to Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/189545/9357)

Comment: @Johnny: *Optimization* != *Factorization*. Title changed.

Comment: @JiveDadson you're hoping right - to add on, this is freshman-grade code, he came to me telling me that his can be "optimized CPU as well". Hoping that STOL will prove him wrong, I've posted it here; there's nothing to be optimized other than the readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of repeating code, have methods such as `PrintGrade()` and `VerifyPassFail()` and call them each time you want to use that chunk of code.
2. Do not declare `int TEZA` earlier, declare it when the `if condition` passes, because only then would you really need to use it.
3. Like the other answer mentioned, you can use a container to hold `m1,m2,m3 and m4`. I would suggest a `std::vector`. If you want to expand to more subjects, all you would have to do is to increase the range of the loop.
4. Additional remark would be not use `using namespace std`, instead go with prefixing the `std` tag such as `std::vector`, `std::cout` etc..

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>

   void PrintGrade( int inInput )
   {
      std::cout << "You got the following mark: ";

      if (inInput >=9 && inInput <=10)
        std::cout<<"A"<<"\n";
      else if (inInput >=8 && inInput <=9)
        std::cout<<"B"<<"\n";
      else if (inInput >=7 && inInput <=8)
        std::cout<<"C"<<"\n";
      else if (inInput >=6 && inInput <=7)
        std::cout<<"D"<<"\n";
      else if (inInput >=5 && inInput <=6)
        std::cout<<"E"<<"\n";
      else if(inInput <5)
        std::cout<<"F"<<"\n";
   }

   void VerifyPassFail( int inInput )
   {
      std::cout<<"\n"<<"DO YOU PASS?: "<<"\n";
      if (inInput >=5)
        std::cout<<"Yes."<<"\n";
      else
        std::cout<<"No."<<"\n";
   }

   int main()
   {
     std::string sub, tf;
     int sum = 0;
     int TEZA;
     std::vector<int> marksList;
     double avg, tzm;

     std::cout << "SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR";
     std::cout << "\n" << "\n" << "Subject at hand?: ";
     std::cin >> sub;
     std::cout << "\n" << "Input the FOUR marks you'd like verified: " << "\n";

     for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
     {
       int marks;
       std::cout<<"\n"<<"M"<<i<<":";
       std::cin>>marks;
       marksList.push_back(marks);
     }

     std::cout << "\n" << "Would you like to include the TEZA grade?(Y/N): ";
     std::cin >> tf;

     for( int i : marksList )
     {
       sum += i;
     }

     avg = (double) sum / 4;

     if (tf == "Y" | tf == "y")
     {
       std::cout << "What is the TEZA grade?: ";
       std::cin >> TEZA;
       int tzm = ((double) avg * 3 + TEZA) / 4;
       std::cout << "\n" << "Your average grade at " << sub << " is " << tzm << "\n"
            << "\n";

       std::cout << "You got the following mark: ";
       PrintGrade(tzm);
       VerifyPassFail(tzm);
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << "\n" << "Average at " << sub << " is " << avg << "\n" << "\n";
       PrintGrade(avg);
       VerifyPassFail(avg);
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: None of that is likely to change what the compiler outputs at all. Optimization without benchmarking is futile.

Comment: I know that it will not affect the compiler output much but the OP also asked if he could " remove some of the repetitions made within the code (such as "if, else if")".

Comment: Sorry. Go in peace.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how he can minimize the code since there is not much scope for performance improvement since it is quite straightforward and as you earlier mentioned extremely IO bound.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted it to be short, I'd probably write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <numeric>

template <class T> T get(std::string const &prompt) {
    std::cout << prompt;
    T ret;
    std::cin >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    auto sub = get<std::string>("SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR\n\nSubject at hand?: ");

    std::cout << "\nPlease enter the FOUR marks you'd like verified:\n";
    std::vector<int> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        m.push_back(get<int>("M" + std::to_string(i + 1) + ": "));

    if (std::toupper(get<char>("\nWould you like to include the TEZA grade?(Y/N): ")) == 'Y')
        m.push_back(get<int>("What is the TEZA grade?: "));

    auto tzm = std::accumulate(m.begin(), m.end(), 0.0) / m.size();

    char const *yn[] = { "No", "Yes" };
    std::cout << "\nYour average grade at " << sub << " is " << tzm 
            << "\n\nYou got the following mark: " << "FFFFFEDCBAA"[(int)tzm] 
            << "\nDo you pass?\n" << yn[tzm >= 5] << "\n";
}
```

I definitely wouldn't turn this in for homework though--I'd not only get a lousy grade, but probably be thrown in an insane asylum as well.

Although the preceding code overdoes some good things, there are some good things hidden in that mess. First of all, using a vector instead of an array. There's almost no circumstance in which it makes real sense to use a raw array in C++. You can use `std::array` or you can use `std::vector` (or any number of other collections), but a raw rarely makes much sense. In this case, we might be dealing with either of two different sizes of collections (i.e., grades including or not including a TEZA grade), so a `vector` makes more sense.

Since a vector keeps track of its own size, we can simplify the code to compute the average by collecting all the grades, *then* computing the average based on the number of grades collected.

We can simplify computation quite a bit by starting with some array-like object of the letter grades, and using the computed numeric grade to index into those letter grades. Using `"FFFFFEDCBAA"[(int)tzm]` is going overboard with terseness. In real life, something like this is more appropriate:

```
std::string letter_grades = ""FFFFFEDCBAA";

std::cout << letter_grades[static_cast<int>(tzm)];
```

At a higher level, the code does quite a bit of the same basic sequence of operations: print out a prompt to the user, then read in a value of some sort. Moving that sequence into a function so we can avoid repeating nearly identical code for the same sequence is (again) quite a good thing to do.

The code in the question also breaks things that can be defined as a single string literal into multiple individual pieces for no apparent reason. I guess *somebody* might find it more understandable that way, but I'm uncertain about who would, or why--it doesn't look like an improvement to me.

It can make sense to break things down on a line-by-line basis, something like this:

```
auto sub = get<std::string>(
    "SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR\n"
    "\n"
    "Subject at hand?: ");
```

The compiler with merge adjacent string literals like this into a single literal, so this ends up exactly like the code shown above--but some find it more readable. Another possibility is to use a raw string:

```
auto sub = get<std::string>(
R"("SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR

Subject at hand?: )");
```

A raw string literal takes everything exactly as-is, including new-line characters, so we can represent a new-line as an actual new-line instead of encoding it as `\n`. I don't find it a huge benefit in this particular situation, but I can see where some people might prefer it.

In the final analysis, the *length* of code is rarely very relevant--but having (for example) repetition in the code does matter--a lot. Getting rid of repetition is definitely a good thing.

Likewise, to the extent we can represent the task in terms of data rather than control flow, that's almost always a win as well.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to run the code after taking a few decades to fully understand it's *true* meanings. It seems like it doesn't work, always displaying some sort of error after fixing it (using GNU compiler).

Comment: @Johnny: It requires C++11 or newer, so you need to pass `std=c++11` when you compile it, as in: "g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp`. It shouldn't need any "fixing" though--it's been tested with gcc 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the parts of the M using an array and a loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string sub, tf;
    int m[4], TEZA, sum;
    double avg, tzm;

    cout << "SIMPLE AVERAGE CALCULATOR";
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "Subject at hand?: "; cin >> sub;
    cout << "\n" << "Input the FOUR marks you'd like verified: " << "\n";
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<"M"<<i<<":"; cin>>m[i-1];
    }
    cout << "\n" << "Would you like to include the TEZA grade?(Y/N): "; cin >> tf;
    sum = m[0] + m[1] + m[2] + m[3];
    avg = (double) sum / 4;

    if (tf == "Y" | tf == "y")
    {
        cout << "What is the TEZA grade?: ";  cin >> TEZA;
        int tzm = ((double) avg * 3 + TEZA) / 4;
        cout << "\n" << "Your average grade at " << sub << " is " << tzm << "\n" << "\n";

        cout << "You got the following mark: ";
        if (tzm >= 9 && tzm <= 10)     cout << "A" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 8 && tzm <= 9) cout << "B" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 7 && tzm <= 8) cout << "C" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 6 && tzm <= 7) cout << "D" << "\n";
        else if (tzm >= 5 && tzm <= 6) cout << "E" << "\n";
        else if (tzm < 5)              cout << "F" << "\n";
        cout << "DO YOU PASS: " << "\n";

        if (tzm >= 5) cout << "Yes." << "\n";
        else cout << "No." << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n" << "Average at " << sub << " is " << avg << "\n" << "\n";
        cout << "You got the following mark: ";
        if (avg >= 9 && avg <= 10) cout << "A" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 8 && avg <= 9) cout << "B" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 7 && avg <= 8) cout << "C" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 6 && avg <= 7) cout << "D" << "\n";
        else if (avg >= 5 && avg <= 6) cout << "E" << "\n";
        else if (avg < 5) cout << "F" << "\n";
        cout << "\n" << "DO YOU PASS?: " << "\n";

        if (avg >= 5) cout << "Yes." << "\n";
        else cout << "No." << "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: You've benchmarked that right? Or compared compiler .asm output?  That was snarky.. Forgive me I doubt that any changes could be made to this code that would do anything a decent optimizing compiler could not do or do better.